# Setting font size in Greek text with TexnicCenter and Miktex

Tags: fonts, fontsize, greek

How is it possible to define the fontsize in documents written in Greek? I am using TexnicCenter and Miktex and trying the following example

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

Ελληνικό Κείμενο 

\end{document}
```

the output is fine. However once I combine two languages, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

Ελληνικό Κείμενο \selectlanguage{english} English Text

\end{document}`
```

the english part just looks terrible in the pdf (pixelated). Similarly if I try to set the fontsize in the beginning, the same happens for the greek part of the text.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

Ελληνικό Κείμενο

\end{document}`
```

I cannot really tell what causes this. Should I be using a different font? Are there some settings that should be used to make everything look OK?

As I was looking for possible solutions I also came across this document that tries to describe some guidelines for the greek language for a different package, but the pdf itself has the same issues (just zoom in and notice the greek text) [lgreekuse.pdf](http://www.cs.brown.edu/system/software/latex/doc/lgreekuse.pdf).

Also here in this document, [greek-usage.pdf](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/generic/babel/greek-usage.pdf) the greek fonts have exactly the same issues.

Comment: After some more searching, I found the greek fonts that are available from the greekfontsociety `http://www.greekfontsociety.gr/` and after installing and using one of them, the text seems fine both in english and greek. This does not happen, however, for the default settings as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get type1 fonts in the english part: Install the cm-super fonts or use `\usepackage{lmodern}`. To get type1 fonts in greek for sizes other than 10pt see [polutonikogreek with lmodern 12pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18747/polutonikogreek-with-lmodern-12pt).