# polutonikogreek with lmodern 12pt

Tags: fonts, babel, greek, latin-modern

Within a document in `ngerman` or `english`, I'd like to have some Greek text using `babel`'s `polutonikogreek`. It seems there are two options for including greek text:

```
\textgreek{mikra'iti mouse~ion}
```

which seems good for single words and short passages, and for longer passages

```
\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek} mikra'iti mouse~ion
```

Using my standard setup (cf. below) including `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`, both options produce ugly pixelated output, technically speaking, it uses a Type 3 font, which doesn't happen for normal text:

[image: pixelated greek]

This problem doesn't appear when using 10pt, in this case, a Type 1 font is used.

**How do I get Type 1 fonts for `polutonikogreek` in 12Pt (and other sizes)?** Here's my setup / a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{mikra'iti mouse~ion}

\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek} mikra'iti mouse~ion

\end{document}
```

I use pdfTeX 1.40.11 by MiKTeX 2.9

Interestingly, this issue appears even in a [manual for the `greek` option in `babel`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/generic/babel/greek-usage.pdf), so it doesn't seem to be trivial. Then again, the manual is from 1997.

P.S.: You'll notice there's also an issue with the circumflex accent, but I thought I'd post this as a separate question once this one's solved.

Comment: what does your log file say about the loaded fonts? See end of the log file

Comment: As for the circumflex accent issue, this seems to be expected for `\textgreek{}`: "Please note that certain symbols cannot have their expected result for Greek text, unless someone has selected the Greek language, e.g., `~` is such a symbol." (from [Writing Greek with the `greek` option of the `babel` package](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/generic/babel/greek-usage.pdf), p. 3)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cheep method to solve this is to tell (pdf)latex to use grmn1000.pfb for all sizes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\DeclareFontFamily{LGR}{lmr}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{lmr}{m}{n}
  {<-> grmn1000}{}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{mikra'iti mouse~ion}

\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek} mikra'iti mouse~ion

\end{document}
```

You will need more `\DeclareFontShape` command for bold etc. Look in lgrlmr.fd for a list.

The other possibility is to install the full set of the cbfonts. As far as I know there is no miktex package so you will have to do it manually. Get cbfonts.zip from CTAN (~70MB!), unzip it somewhere outside the miktex folders. You will get a folder

```
cbfonts/fonts/map
             /type1
             /....  
       /tex
```

In `cbfonts/fonts/map` there is a cbgreek-full.map. Move it to `cbfonts/fonts/map/dvips` (miktex seems to ignore maps directly in fonts/map).

Then add the root folder `cbfonts` as a new root in miktex settings as in admin mode (for all users) or user mode (only for you).
Call on the command line `initexmf --admin --edit-config-file updmap` (admin mode) or `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap` (user mode) which will open a updmap.cfg. Add `Map cbgreek-full.map`, save it. Then run `updmap --admin` or `updmap`. After this your example should use grmn1200.pfb for the 12pt greek.

Comment: I tried to install cbfonts, but it still doesn't work. I downloaded [cbfonts.zip](http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/greek/cbfonts.zip), and did all your steps. My example still uses the same font (I think `grmn1200.pk`). Possible sources for confusion: 1) I have the multi-user install of MiKTeX. 2) Folder names `cbfonts` vs. `cb`, see Leo Liu's post. 3) Should I add `Map cbgreek-fullmap` or `Map cbgreek-fullmap.map` to `updmap.cfg`? The other entries list the file extension (`Map clm.map` and `Map libertine.map` -- another potential source of the problem?)

Comment: Yes, sorry I had a type it should be `Map cbgreek-fullmap.map`. I edited my answer. And I added instructions for multiuser setup (as I have a singleuser installation I can't test them but imho they should be correct.)

Comment: Nope, still nothing. I just did a complete reinstall of MiKTeX because something got messed up along the way and nothing was working anymore, and then went through your instructions A–Z again (both single user and admin), but still no new font. Is it possible that there's interference with `cfr-lm`, that I installed according to the question [Oldstylenums with Latin Modern](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14274/4012)? (Btw, your cheap method works, but I'd really like to have the real thing working.)

Comment: No they can't be an interference with cfr-lm. But they can be an interference if you mixed admin and user calls. Run on the command line "updmap --verbose > updmap.log" Then put the content of the log-file together with the log-file of the pdflatex run somewhere for inspection (check if it contains personal data you don't want to post).

Comment: [updmap.log](http://db.tt/sMmJ22p) + [greek.log](http://db.tt/lE7Jiqv). Thanks so much for your extensive help!

Comment: updmap is not using the Map. Either it can't find it or it is not mentioned in one of the cfg. At first update the FNDB as user with `initexmf -u`. At the start of the updmap.log are the pathes of three updmap.cfg. Open them and check if one of them contain the Map-entry. If not add it to the one in `C:\users`. Then run `updmap` again.

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\updmap.cfg` doesn't contain `cbgreek-fullmap.map`. `C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config\updmap.cfg` and `C:\Users\F****\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config\updmap.cfg` do contain `Map cbgreek-fullmap.map`. So I had done the `initexmf -u` first, then checked, changed nothing (because it was present in 2 out of 3), ran `updmap`; but this didn't change anything about the output :(

Comment: Hm. Did you move the map cbgreek-full from fonts/map to fonts/map/dvips? What does `kpsewhich cbgreek-fullmap.map` say? For good measure also call `initexmf --admin -u` as I don't know how you added the root.

Comment: I did, actually, I copied it, so it's both in `cbfonts/fonts/map` and `cbfonts/fonts/map/dvips` (I had to create this folder, it hadn't been there yet). `kpsewhich cbgreek-fullmap.map` doesn't say anything at all. `initexmf --admin -u` doesn't help.

Comment: I think I got it: I didn't forget a `map` in my first answer but simply a dot. The name of the map-file is `cbgreek-full.map`. So correct the updmap.cfg

Comment: Yes! This did it! Thank you so much! To keep this question decently clean, should we delete all the comments once you've edited your answer? (You can also removed the differentiation between user and admin, I made the edit as a user, so it doesn't seem to make any difference)

Answer (score 2):

I can’t see any problems with your MWE. My Setup ist MacTeX (~ TeX Live 2010) width `pdflatex` 3.1415926-1.40.11 maybe you need to update your system?!
[image]

### My file list

get it with `\listfiles` before the `\documentclass` command

```
*File List*
article.cls 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size12.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
babel.sty 2008/07/06 v3.8l The Babel package
greek.ldf 2005/03/30 v1.3l Greek support from the babel system
lgrenc.def 2008/06/17 v2.3 Greek Encoding
english.ldf 2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system
fontenc.sty
t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
lmodern.sty 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
lgrcmr.fd 2008/06/17 v2.3 Greek Computer Modern
t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
lgrlmr.fd 2008/06/17 v2.3 Greek Latin Modern
```

Comment: @Tobi: I just ran an update and there was nothing to update. I think it might have something to do with the fonts I have installed, or rather the ones I don't.

Comment: @doncherry: I added my file list to my answer so you can compare it with yours.

Comment: I checked my file list, it wasn't different in any important respect. It seems the problem was MiKTeX-specific. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @doncherry: Sorry, that it didn’t help … but I’m glad to see that Ulrike solved you problem :-)

Comment: Don't worry, it was interesting seeing that this seems to work better with TeX Live, and I learned about `\listfiles`, which I hadn't known before.

Comment: @doncherry: At least a bit … :-)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that some fonts are not installed properly. It is not very easy to examine the problem, and I don't use MiKTeX (but TeX Live).

Anyway, search your MiKTeX directory for these files.

These should exist, since you compiled the document without errors:

- `lgrlmr.fd` at `???/tex/generic/babel/`
- `grmn1200.tfm` at `???/fonts/tfm/public/cbfonts/`

And this may be absent:

- `grmn1200.pfb` at `???/fonts/type1/public/cbfonts/` (Type1 font for Greek Latin Modern 12pt)

If the `.pfb` file does not exist or at a wrong position, you should reinstall `cbfonts` package using MiKTeX's Package Manager, or install it manally.

If the file is OK, this may be wrong:

- `pdftex.map` at `???/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/` with a line:

  ```
  grmn1200 grmn1200 <grmn1200.pfb
  ```

You may need to edit the `updmap.cfg` and run `updmap` utility to make the fonts valid.

---

From your comment and packages in `CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/`, it seems that MiKTeX has no full latest `cb` fonts for greek, but only the fonts for 10pt.

You'd better write a letter to MiKTeX mailing list to report the problem and ask for update.

And if you want to use the fonts now, you must install the full fonts manually from CTAN. It isn't easy for newbies, indeed.

You can get all fonts at:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/greek/cbfonts-all

1. Extract all the files and copy them to the MiKTeX's TDS root directory.
2. Run updmap following Ulrike Fischer's advice. The key is to add `cbgreek-full.map` and make it active.
3. Use it.

Comment: 1) `lgrmlr.fd` is present. 2) `???/fonts/tfm/public/cbfonts/` doesn't exist, but there is `???/fonts/tfm/public/cb/`. The latter doesn't contain `grmn1200.tfm`, but `grmn1000.tfm`. 3) Again, there's just ``???/fonts/type1/public/cb`, which contains only `grmn1000.pfb`. 4) As for `cbfonts`, afaik this isn't a package, but a font collection, which is why it doesn't show up in the package manager nor can be installed as a package manually? 5) `???/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap` doesn't exist either. I've updated `updmap.cfg` several times while trying Ulrike's advice. That's all pretty strange?

Comment: There should be some naming differences between MiKTeX and TeX Live, it doesn't matter. However, `grmn1000.pfb` and `grmn1000.tfm` are fonts of 10pt, there's no fonts for 12pt. I checked MiKTeX's `cbgreek.cab` in CTAN, it's old and incomplete. That's MiKTeX's issue.

Comment: Or, if you don't mind, you can use TeX Live instead. Personally, I prefer TeX Live than MiKTeX. (MiKTeX has its advantage, of course.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, as you suggested, Ulrike's advice has solved the issue. I'm indeed considering switching to TeX Live, I'll have to look into it some time.