# Error in TeX Live – Font ... not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, errors, packages, texlive, font-encodings

I freshly installed **'basic'** version of TeX Live 2012 (not full, only basic version).

I have following line in my code:
`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

I get following error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty:100: Font T1/cmr/
m/n/10=ecrm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty:100:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I understand that some packages are missing, however I do not know which ones.

Also, solution to this problem on most of the earlier posts is to install ubuntu latex recommended package, however please note that I am not using LaTeX from Ubuntu's software center (which is old TeX Live 2009) but rather have manually installed basic version of TeX Live 2012 as per instructions here: http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Please let me know how do I solve this issue (I don't want to install complete version of TeX Live 2012, only those packages necessary to run this piece of code).

Comment: Do you have the [`cm-super`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cm-super) package installed?

Comment: You should do `sudo tlmgr install ec` and `sudo tlmgr install cm-super`. But the best thing you can do is to install the full version or you'll be always confronting with missing packages.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, your answer solved my problem.

Comment: At least in R/RStudio, you can install the tinytext package, which automatically installs missing dependencies: 

if (!require('tinytex')) install.packages('tinytex'); library('tinytex')
 
And then: 
 
tinytex::install_tinytex()

Answer (score 118, accepted):

In this case, the missing file is `ecrm1000.tfm` according to the error message. To know which package it belongs to, you can use the command `tlmgr search --file ecrm1000.tfm --global` which finds it in package `ec`. So you have to install it with `tlmgr install ec`.

Then you may have other errors, other files to look up and other packages to install. Since the process may be cumbersome, you may want to install at least `collection-latexrecommended` and `collection-fontsrecommended` if you really don't want a full install.

An alternative would be to use the `texliveonfly` http://ctan.org/pkg/texliveonfly package which installs missing packages on the fly (see its documentation).

Comment: I had to add `--global` switch to find the file because otherwise the search appears to be only in the local installation: `tlmgr search --file ecrm1000.tfm --global`

Comment: `tlmgr install collection-latexrecommended` was a lifesaver for document class `leaflet`

Answer (score 133):

I just installed the recommended fonts and it worked for me. =)
The command for a [Debian based Linux distribution](https://www.debian.org/misc/children-distros)  (including [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/) and [Mint](https://linuxmint.com/)):

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

Comment: It's working well :)

Comment: This is much more straight-forward solution for the problem than the other ad-hoc fix. It worked for me.

Comment: In tex live this is collection-fontsrecommended.

Comment: I used `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommends --no-install-recommends` which reduced the size to only around 5 MB

Comment: This solution works and doesn't require me to manually install seventeen different packages. Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

In case you are on Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install texlive-collection-fontsrecommended.noarch
```

Comment: Works for OpenSUSE as well (as: `sudo zypper install texlive-collection-fontsrecommended`).

Answer (score 15):

On macOS / [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/) install `collection-fontsrecommended` in the TeX Live Utility or `tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended` from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I had multiple errors for several fonts with the `textgreek` package (`Corrupted NFSS tables`) and with XeTeX or better `hyperref` (`Font \XeTeXLink@font=pzdr at 0.00002pt not loadable`).

*Edit*: I found out ([in this post](https://tex-live.tug.narkive.com/Ye3E5dgL/dependency-missing-in-osx-mactex-basictex-2013)) and by running `tlmgr info pzdr` that the error caused by the `hyperref` package can be fixed with the `zapfding` package because there is a `pzdr.afm` and a `pzdr.tfm` in the `zapfding` package. After installing `zapfding` everyting was working. The `cbfonts` like I mention below is not needed for me anymore.

<sub>Maybe `cbfonts` was needed for the other errors. I was able to fix the mentioned error `Font \XeTeXLink@font=pzdr at 0.00002pt not loadable` by using only `zapfding`. I cannot say something about the other "multiple errors for several fonts" anymore because I am working on a different TeX setup now.  I am leaving the original answer below in case that the other errors were really caused by `textgreek`.</sub>

---

**Original Post**

I tried to load the fonts like @mpg describes it but some errors were still present. For some fonts I didn't even get a result when I run `tlmgr search --file <name> --global` (e.g. `LGRcmr.fd` or some others).

I ended up with installing the huge `cbfonts` via `tlmgr` (`tlmgr install cbfonts`) like of [@Ulrike Fischer suggested in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18751/147291). This works now for me.

Answer (score 0):

In `archlinux` the package name is `texlive-fontsrecommended`

Installing it resolved my issue.