# How to write a single Hiragana character in latex

Tags: fonts

I've run out of letters and I would like to use the Hiragana ''ro'' in a latex document. How can I produce it in the simplest way?

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there also a way to use the Katana alphabet, single selected letters only?

Comment: @ Mike Ruge [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). If you have another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions) please post it on the main question side. It will not be seen here. I just saw it coincidentally. Also please do not forget to provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to clarify your problem. You may also refer to this question and describe why the answers here did not helped you with your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This example works with `lua-`, `xe-`, `pdf-` and with plain `latex` (followed by `dvips` and `ps2pdf` conversion).

```
% run: *latex mal-japanese.tex
% or 
% latex mal-japanese.tex
% dvips mal-japanese.dvi
% ps2pdf mal-japanese.ps
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
% pdftex testfont
% --> dmjhira
% --> \table\bye
\font\maljapanese=dmjhira at 2ex % This is a matter of taste.
Some text {\maljapanese\char"4D} before $a+\textrm{\maljapanese\char"4D}=c$ some text {\maljapanese\char"4D} after.
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: In case your TeX installation complains about missing files/fonts, have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75166/error-in-tex-live-font-not-loadable-metric-tfm-file-not-found
I solved running `tlmgr install wadalab`

Answer (score 19):

I'm not sure people reading your document will understand the symbol or know how to pronounce it. However, here's a way without loading the whole `CJKutf8`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ろ}{\text{\usefont{U}{min}{m}{n}\symbol{'215}}}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{min}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{min}{m}{n}{<-> udmj30}{}

\begin{document}
$a+ろ=c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have problems in typing the character directly, just define a command for it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\hiraro}{\text{\usefont{U}{min}{m}{n}\symbol{'215}}}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{min}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{min}{m}{n}{<-> udmj30}{}

\begin{document}
$a+\hiraro=c$
\end{document}
```

Here's the complete table of the `udmj30` font, if you want to extend the usage to other Hiragana:

[image]

In case you don't have `udmj30` (probably due to an incomplete TeX distribution), you can try `dmjhira`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\hiraro}{\text{\usefont{U}{min}{m}{n}\symbol{'115}}}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{min}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{min}{m}{n}{<-> dmjhira}{}

\begin{document}
$a+\hiraro=c$
\end{document}
```

Here's the table of the font:

[image]

The syntax is `\symbol{'<octal number>}` or `\symbol{"<hexadecimal number>}` or also `\symbol{<decimal number>}`. Just look up the table for the correct number.

Comment: Thanks. I've found the following error while compiling: Package newunicodechar Error: ASCII character requested

Comment: @user17786 Are you saving your file as UTF-8?

Comment: @user17786 I've added an alternative way.

Comment: Thanks. It now says that the font udmj30 is not loadable. But Malipivo's slutins is working fine.

Comment: @user17786 I'll add the correction for using `dmjhira`

Comment: This worked fine.

Comment: In case your TeX installation complains about missing files/fonts, have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75166/error-in-tex-live-font-not-loadable-metric-tfm-file-not-found
I solved running `tlmgr install wadalab`

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainjfont{MS Mincho}    
\newcommand{\HiraganaRo}{ろ}

\begin{document}
\[\HiraganaRo = 42\]
In the formula I use the symbol \HiraganaRo{} which is taken from the Japanese Hiragana alphabet.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great, but I use plain latex.

Comment: @user17786 Are you using `latex` or `pdflatex`?

Comment: good point. I'm using pdflatex.

Answer (score 1):

This code uses the ろ symbol from your TrueType or OpenType font of choice.  I chose Harano Aji Mincho, which comes *libre* with TeX Live, [or here](https://github.com/trueroad/HaranoAjiFonts).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newfontfamily\japanesefont{HaranoAjiMincho}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  % Set other features, such as ligatures and forms, here.
  Script=Kana,
  Language=Japanese]

\newcommand\jpRo{\textup{\japanesefont ろ}}
\newunicodechar{ろ}{\jpRo}

\begin{document}
% You probably want to change your section title format to
% something like \large\bfseries\boldmath, not insert
% \boldmath commands.
\section*{\boldmath The Symbol \(ろ = 42\)}

This paper uses the symbol \(ろ = 42\).
\end{document}
```

[image: Hirano Aji Mincho sample]

The above definition will, as you see, appear bold like the surrounding text and math when you use `\boldmath\bfseries`, but will stay upright even when the surrounding text is italicized, such as in a theorem statement.  If you are not using `\boldmath` and you want all math symbols to appear in normal weight in the header, as in AMS style, change the definition of `\jpRo` to

```
\newcommand\jpRo{\textnormal{\japanesefont ろ}}
```

In hindsight, if you ever need ロ in the future, it would have been better to call this something like `\hiriganaRo` or `\jpHgRo`.  Either way, it’s an ASCII macro you can use.