# Typeset the shrug ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ emoji

Tags: unicode, characters, fun

I'm completing a problem set, one problem for which I literally have no idea what to do on. The graders would prefer to have a physical copy of the problem so I thought it best to include the `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` emoji as my answer, instead of something like "Dunno" or "No idea."

Option #1 is to include an image.

Beyond that I actually don't understand how this emoji works. The middle character is Japanese kana "tsu" and proves problematic - TeX wants it in math mode then renders "?" when it is.

Comment: You'd, er, yeah probably have to use XeTeX or LuaTeX. Having said that, I think there are old packages for Japanese available, but is it *really* worth it? Even if you don't just want to put a ? or something, couldn't you just go for :S or \*shrug\*. I mean, it's pretty straightforward with XeTeX (although not worth it in my book), but if you're not already familiar with it, I just wouldn't bother for this bit of fun

Comment: Have you used `\textbackslash` for the backslash and escaped the underscores? Also have you tried XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with `fontspec` to make sure your font supports it?

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171611/55879) also deals with getting kana in LaTeX; I think once you figure that out, the rest will be much easier.

Comment: Off-topic, I guess, but: Instead of researching how to cutely disclose that you do not know how to do the problem, why not work on the problem?  It will be more beneficial to your grade and your learning if you write *something*, even the things you tried that didn't work.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I did actually solve the problem. This was more of a hedge.

Comment: @djechlin Certainly a weird way to hedge though to say the least :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Playing a bit with tikz, this is what I got:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\shrug}[1][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,x=0.8\ht\strutbox,y=0.8\ht\strutbox,line width=0.125ex,#1]
\def\arm{(-2.5,0.95) to (-2,0.95) (-1.9,1) to (-1.5,0) (-1.35,0) to (-0.8,0)};
\draw \arm;
\draw[xscale=-1] \arm;
\def\headpart{(0.6,0) arc[start angle=-40, end angle=40,x radius=0.6,y radius=0.8]};
\draw \headpart;
\draw[xscale=-1] \headpart;
\def\eye{(-0.075,0.15) .. controls (0.02,0) .. (0.075,-0.15)};
\draw[shift={(-0.3,0.8)}] \eye;
\draw[shift={(0,0.85)}] \eye;
% draw mouth
\draw (-0.1,0.2) to [out=15,in=-100] (0.4,0.95); 
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
Well, \shrug\ or maybe \shrug[x=1ex,y=1ex,blue]?
{\Huge or a huge \shrug}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks perfect and drops right in! Big success.

Comment: There seems to be a huge fondness of TikZ in this community, but using this monster to replicate this simple example seems an unnecessary complication. Sorry to downvote, but standard LaTeX’s `qbezier`s would be a more lightweight solution.

Comment: @AndreïKostyrka Don't worry, I don't mind your down vote (especially since you explained it) and respect your opinion (but do not agree with it).

Answer (score 33):

Free version with the default font and `pdflatex`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,rotate}
\begin{document}
\rule[1.3ex]{.25em}{1pt}\kern-.1em%
\reflectbox{\small\ttfamily/}%
\kern-.1em\rule[-.2ex]{.4em}{1pt}%
\makebox{{\raisebox{.15em}{{\large\textcircled{
\ttfamily\kern-.35em%
\rotatebox[origin=t]{-120}{\bfseries\scriptsize`\kern-.3ex`}%
\kern-.15em\rotatebox{-45}{\bfseries\scriptsize)}}}}%
\rule[-.2ex]{.4em}{1pt}\kern-.1em{\small\ttfamily/}%
\kern-.1em\rule[1.3ex]{.25em}{1pt}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: imo, this version looks _really_ nice. It has the perfect smirk that just screams "no idea".

Answer (score 32):

I used xelatex here, and specified the font that firefox used on my system to display your title. But switched to Arial for the arms as MS PGothic has a Yen in the backslash slot (long story:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{MS Gothic}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\begin{document}


 \textsf{¯\char92\string_}(ツ)\textsf{\string_/¯ }


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the answer +1, however you've missed out a backslash - the correct appearance is ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ This may be because the OP hasn't escaped the backslash in the question body (I was gonna edit it, but it'd be a one character edit and I didn't have anything else to add)

Comment: @Au101 yes noticed that, but then I noticed that that font has a yen symbol in that backslash slot, just looking to fix...

Comment: I'd forgotten about that! Not that you need to know this, but I have quite a soft spot for MS PGothic, one of the few pretty sans serif fonts with bars on the I (something I once desired after getting a telling-off for spelling a surname with a ""lower case l""). I'd just use a different font if I were you

Comment: How about using `\reflectbox{/}` to avoid the yen symbol?

Comment: @Au101 try now:-)

Comment: Sadly you've had me upvote already, but that all looks good to me :)

Answer (score 20):

This works with pdflatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\newcommand{\textoverline}{$\overline{\mbox{\phantom{L}}}$}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
\textoverline\verb|\_(ツ)_/|\textoverline
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And for XeLaTeX, an alternative to David's answer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\myfont{MS PGothic}
\begin{document}
{\myfont ¯\reflectbox{/}\string_(ツ)\string_/¯ }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

A bit late...

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\shrug{\texttt{\raisebox{0.75em}{\char`\_}\char`\\\char`\_\kern-0.5ex(\kern-0.25ex\raisebox{0.25ex}{\rotatebox{45}{\raisebox{-.75ex}"\kern-1.5ex\rotatebox{-90})}}\kern-0.5ex)\kern-0.5ex\char`\_/\raisebox{0.75em}{\char`\_}}}
\begin{document}
\tiny\shrug

\scriptsize\shrug

\footnotesize\shrug

\small\shrug

\normalsize\shrug

\large\shrug

\Large\shrug

\huge\shrug

\Huge\shrug
\end{document}
```

[image]