# Behavior of text character under subscript in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, subscripts

I defined the following macro (thanks to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171611/how-to-write-a-single-hiragana-character-in-latex) question)

```
\font\maljapanese=dmjhira at 2.5ex
\newcommand{\yo}{\textrm{\!\maljapanese\char"48}}
```

which prints the Hiragana letter よ. This works fine in both text and inline math mode, but its size does not scale correctly when I use it in a subscript in math mode. In fact, it does not scale at all:

```
Inline: $a$; subscript: $f_a$.

Inline: $\yo$; subscript: $f_\yo$.
```

[image]

How can I reasonably fix this? I could add a version of `\yo`, say `\subyo`, which prints よ in a smaller font, but it does not seem elegant at all.

Comment: You should ***never*** use `\font` in LaTeX.

Comment: @egreg Apologies, I was looking for a quick and dirty way to print that character. I tried to use ```\char"3088``` but my compiler didn't like it. What can I use instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should *never* use `\font` in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{dmjhira}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{dmjhira}{m}{n}{ <-> dmjhira }{}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\yo}{\text{\usefont{U}{dmjhira}{m}{n}\symbol{"48}}}

\begin{document}

$f_{\yo}+\yo$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you need other Hiragana characters, here's the complete font table of `dmjhira`

[image]

However, you should think twice (or more) whether inflicting your readers strange symbols that they know nothing about.

Comment: The Hiragana よ is sometimes used to denote the Yoneda embedding. In any case, this is for my own notes and there's a very small chance that someone else will read them.

Comment: @egreg -- The hiragana character numbered 46 in this chart was requested for the STIX project, so use of *some* such symbols is not unknown in western math documents.