# Error in MacTex – Font … not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, errors, packages, texlive, font-encodings

This question is exactly the same as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75166/error-in-tex-live-font-not-loadable-metric-tfm-file-not-found), but for Mac OS. My error is:

`Font OT1/pcr/m/n/9=pcrr7t at 9.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found`

So I tried the answer in the linked question. My missing file is `pcrr7t.tfm`. When I tried `tlmgr search --file pcrr7t.tfm`, it is found in:

```
courier:  
texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/courier/pcrr7t.tfm
```

Therefore, I tried to install courier with `sudo tlmgr install courier`. It turned out I already have courier.

tlmgr: package repository              http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/systems/texlive/tlnet
  tlmgr install: package already present: courier

But then why I can't compile the tex file. Thanks in advance.

---

## UPDATE

This error (and some others of the same kind) only occurs when I run `pdflatex draft.tex`. I can compile OK with `TeXShop`. But I only want to run from command line.

Comment: Just in case (I already met a similar problem with MiKTeX on Windows):  run `initexmf --mkmaps` from the command line. It might a problem with the psfonts database (psfonts.map and the like). Also check if the font is mentioned in `updmap.cfg`.

Comment: Can you try `sudo mktexlsr`?

Comment: @egreg: yes, the problem persists.

Comment: Try `sudo tlmgr install --reinstall courier`

Comment: @egreg I just did, the problem persists :-(

Comment: I guess you have two installations of TeX Live. What does `which pdftex` return?

Comment: @egreg I don't think so. Here is the path: `/opt/local/bin/pdftex`

Comment: What does `which tlmgr` return?

Comment: @qsp That means the terminal is using TeX Live from MacPorts; are you sure TeXShop does the same? Note that `tlmgr` is *not* provided by the MacPorts distribution, so it will update the MacTeX distribution.

Comment: @cfr: perhaps egreg is right, I have `/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr`

Comment: @egreg: yes, I installed from MacPorts. Could you tell me how I can check which pdftex TeXShop is using. Please tolerate my stupidity, I have just started using Mac 3 days ago (a machine from my project).

Comment: @qsp Do a very simple thing: remove the MacPorts TeX Live.

Comment: @egreg: I removed it, and the command line now works like a charm. Thank you very much. Could you please turn your comment to an answer so I can close this question :) Or should I delete this question, because it is too trivial (not for me though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a problem due to having two distinct TeX Live distributions (which was confirmed in the comments).

You seem to have both a MacTeX provided TeX Live, which is the one used by TeXShop by default (the binaries are in `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin`, with a symbolic link at `/Library/TeX/texbin`, which is added to the `PATH` environment variable) and also the MacPorts one, that installs its binaries in `/opt/local/bin`.

Note that the latter distribution doesn't provide `tlmgr`, so this program is executed from the MacTeX binaries. However, MacPorts places `/opt/local/bin` high in the `PATH` variable, so when you run `pdflatex` from the terminal, the MacPorts binary is used (and the TeX tree corresponding to it). To the contrary, TeXShop is usually configured to run the binaries in `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

So, running `tlmgr` does no good to the MacPorts distribution, that has its own package manager.

I know, this looks complicated, but there's a very easy solution: get rid of the TeX Live provided by MacPorts.

Comment: I have the same problem after installing a 2016 version of MacTex on Mac OS 10.9.5 for use with TexMaker 4.5 (see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293576/how-to-install-texmaker-on-mac)). I think that a second distribution can be present that causes the problem of the missing TFM file. So far, I have found the correct distribution in HD/Library/TeX, but I cannot find the other one (`opt/local/bin` - there is no folder `opt`, even after showing the hidden files and folders in finder).