# how to compile Lualatex from terminal?

Tags: luatex, compiling

I am writing my phd thesis now, and all these while I have used texshop in mac os X (mavericks). I have compiled in Lualatex through texshop (or even texworks) and the file compiles fine, but I have a problem compiling it from the command line and get many errors like this :

```
   lualatex --shall-escape Report.tex 
    .
    .
    .
   ! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `lgrenc.def' not found.
   (fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.

    See the fontenc package documentation for explanation.
    Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Very typical latex compilation errors. My simple question is how to compile using lualatex from the command line?

Comment: withou seeing the source it is hard to tell, but a couplw of thing jump out. It shpuld be `--shell-escape`, and you should not be using `fontenc` with lualatex. Apart from that, the error ypu have shown are not related to lualatex, and pdflatex would probably crash the same way.

Comment: You have been using `fontenc` with `lualatex` this whole time? This is not (usually) recommended! Or is some package loading it "behind the scenes"?  It is hard to tell without an actual, but minimal `.tex`  file....

Comment: Welcome! You almost certainly don't want to be using `lgrenc.def` with LuaLaTeX in any case... But, again, without code it is hard to say.  That said, the error you are getting is odd. `lgrenc.def` should  be *found*. Loading it may well cause problems. But there should not be a problem loading it.  Hard to say more without some more details, though. How did you install TeX exactly?

Comment: My impression is that you have two TeX Live distributions, one installed as MacTeX and the other, probably, with MacPorts. Can you add the output you get from giving `which lualatex` from the terminal?

Comment: @egreg     which lualatex  --   /opt/local/bin/lualatex    I dont know how to put up the tex file its so big, but the confusion (for me ) arises as to how does texshop compile it ?

Comment: @AyanMitra As I suspected, you have a MacPorts TeX Live that kicks in. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271525/error-in-mactex-font-not-loadable-metric-tfm-file-not-found

Comment: @AyanMitra as you have found a solution, perhaps you could make it an answer which would be more useful to visitors than having to read the whole question til the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by others in the comments, I found the macports installed binaries

```
port provides /opt/local/bin/latex
```

Then simply uninstall it

```
sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents texlive-bin
```

Now if you do which lualatex it shows

```
/usr/texbin/lualatex
```

The other shortcut I realised could be directly accessing the mactex binaries by

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin/lualatex  Report.tex
```

and put an alias to this path and then simply calling lualatex will invoke the texshop used same binaries, and that's what I am doing now and everything works fine.

Comment: You may want to look into updating your TeX distribution to MacTeX2015. LuaTeX and LuaLaTeX, in particular, have changed significantly since MacTeX2012.