# Getting TexLive Recommended Fonts after installing MacTex-2015 on El Capitan

Tags: fonts, texlive, mactex

I downloaded and installed MacTeX-2015 on a brand new Mac OS/X El Capitan system, then ran `pdfTeX` (i.e. Plain TeX) on an old .tex file and got the following error that I'm hoping you can help me resolve:

```
\font\reffont=rptmrrn at 9.5pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

The .tex file is Plain TeX, and runs fine on an ancient Snow Leopard system where it used to live.  The offending line in the .tex file is:

```
\font\reffont=rptmrrn at 9.5pt
```

I suspect the `rptmrrn` font is missing in the MacTeX-2015 system I installed on the El Capitan system.

I found a tex.stackexchange question that suggests I need to download and install the TeX Live Recommended Fonts: 
[Error in TeX Live – Font ... not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75166/error-in-tex-live-font-not-loadable-metric-tfm-file-not-found)

But this seems to suggest the font is already installed:

`cat /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts.map | grep rptmrrn`

yields:

`rptmrrn NimbusRomNo9L-Regu " .82 ExtendFont StandardEncoding ReEncodeFont " <8a.enc <utmr8a.pfb`

So, my questions are: (1) Would downloading the TeX Live Recommended Fonts fix my font problem?  (2) If so, how does one do that on a Mac that is based on TeX Live 2015? and (3) I have several other fonts defined in the .tex file, and I'm hoping that whatever loads this font will ensure all the other fonts are loaded, too. [not really a question!]

Thank you!