# latex font not found

Tags: fonts

I am having following error:

```
phthalo1.log: 1655: ! Font OT1/cmr/m/n/4=cmr4 at 4.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
phthalo1.log: 1708: LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+phv on input line 35.
phthalo1.log: 1710: (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd
phthalo1.log: 1711: File: ot1phv.fd 2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for OT1/phv.
```

However, I have full `texlive` distro installed.
Also, I get

```
# tlmgr search --file cmr4.tfm --global
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.imsc.res.in/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
[root@roddur rudra]# tlmgr install tlnet
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.imsc.res.in/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr install: package tlnet not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

This question is similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75166/error-in-tex-live-font-not-loadable-metric-tfm-file-not-found) but that doesnt solve my problem.
Kindly help.

**EDIT**
**stdout**

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm cmr4
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for cmr4.
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input cmr4
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf cmr4
! I can't find file `cmr4'.
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input cmr4

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input cmr4

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: cmr4.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input cmr4' failed to make cmr4.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font OT1/cmr/m/n/4=cmr4 at 4.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.11 \maketitle

?
```

**.fd lines in log**

```
 grep .fd phthalo1.log 
phthalo1.log:  403: Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
phthalo1.log:  430: File: pd1enc.def 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
phthalo1.log: 1101: \pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen317
phthalo1.log: 1102: \pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen318
phthalo1.log: 1103: \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen319
phthalo1.log: 1104: \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen320
phthalo1.log: 1107: \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen322
phthalo1.log: 1108: \pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen323
phthalo1.log: 1108: \pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen323
phthalo1.log: 1695: (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
phthalo1.log: 1696: File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
phthalo1.log: 1700: (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
phthalo1.log: 1701: File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
phthalo1.log: 1705: (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd
phthalo1.log: 1706: File: ursfs.fd 1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)
phthalo1.log: 1710: (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd
phthalo1.log: 1711: File: ot1phv.fd 2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for OT1/phv.
phthalo1.log: 1733: (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd
phthalo1.log: 1734: File: omscmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Are you using beamer? Is is up-to-date?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This was working fine until I reinstalled texlive. And over years, my input file has grown up a lot. I have tried to find out where the problem is to make a mwe and failed.

Comment: I have installed it a week ago.

Comment: can you show more of the log (in particular fd files) there should not be a cmr4 specified (cmr5 is the smallest) so it looks like you have non standard font declarations

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's why I asked about beamer, it had this non-standard declaration (and not in a fd-file).

Comment: which one, please? can you kindly specify?

Comment: Could you at first answer my questions?

Comment: about beamer? yes...it is beamer, and it is uptodate.

Comment: What is the beamer version?

Comment: I am lot sure how I can check that, but I have installed it from texlive distro:
`install-tl-20170910`

Comment: Look in the log-file. The version is behind "beamer.cls".

Comment: This is what tlmgr told me:
installed:   Yes
revision:    45142
sizes:       doc: 4965k, run: 1401k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 3.43
cat-date:    2017-08-27 16:42:28 +0200
cat-license: lppl1.3cgpl2+fdl
cat-topics:  presentation class
collection:  collection-latexrecommended

Comment: Look in the log-file of the latex-compilation. phthalo1.log.

Comment: Document Class: beamer 2017/08/22 v3.43 A class for typesetting presentations

Comment: Hm. Ok it looks as if they corrected the bug I reported only partly. As a work-around try to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, I will make a bug report for the problem with OT1.

Comment: Can you make this an answer, so that I can make it accepted?

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened to me after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10.
The problem was solved by installing the texlive-fonts-extra package.