# tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, update

I'm not able to get past this error. I do not wish to do a fresh install of texlive. Why is `texlive` so frickin annoying? Why does it force me too fresh install? Why can't I just upgrade `texlive` like any other piece of software? Why can't I just use the older version? Why can't I live in peace?

```
nikhil@spyder:~/report$ tlmgr install listings
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

Comment: Welcome! As it stands, this is more a rant than a question. What do you want help with? As you probably know, we are not responsible for the design of TeX Live. (Of course, someone who is may answer your question, but if you really want it answered as such, this isn't the best place.) I would say: it is not really TL which is annoying you, but Debian's packaging of TL. Luckily, you can install the packages you need using `apt` without needing to update your TL installation. If you had an upstream install, you could just keep using the 2017 version. So nothing forces you to update either way.

Comment: Package updates might be using new features of TeX Live 2018, for instance.

Comment: @cfr You are right. This was intended to be a question more than a rant but turned out to be the opposite. I still don't blame myself though. I simply wanted to get rid of this error and install the `listings` package peacefully. Sorry if that is not evident from the question. Thanks for your insights though. I wasn't aware that I could simply install packages using `apt`.

Comment: Or, you can switch to [MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/download), if you prefer a rolling release model. Now MiKTeX is also available for Linux and MacOS and it's no longer a Windows-exclusive TeX distro.

Comment: What is the problem of downloading `update-tlmgr-latest` from the URL shown and run it? It is not more complicated as running `tlmgr`, and not "frickin annoying". What do you mean with "like any other piece of software"? If you talk about Linux software, then stick to the outdated distribution packages. If you talk about software in general, then note that e.g. under Windows basically ALL software need a new EXE downloaded and executed on major version changes.

Comment: I have remove comments here which were not directly related to the topic at hand.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This seems to do the trick. The solution is to downgrade the repository to 2017 version. This seems to be easy enough, but a quick search for the error did not suggest anything of this sort.

```
sudo tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final
```

Comment: this is "staying at tl2017" as I mentioned in my answer. If you had updated with tlmgr before texlive 2018 was released then this will never do anything as the `tlnet-final` are just fixed snapshots they will never be updated so you will get no updates via that repository.

Comment: In addition, unlike a normal ctan mirror that uses a distributed mirrored network to share load around the globe, this is directly hitting TUG's main server, that server is _not_ set up as a global delivery network, and is designed for occasional one-off downloads of the archived systems.

Comment: Noting the concerns in the above comments, this answer still serves as a great temporary _workaround_. Thanks!

Comment: I need this workaround _every year_ between the time of the official release and the time I actually get around to upgrading my TL installation.

Comment: trying this same trick (but with 2018 and 2019), I get:
`tlmgr: main database at ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2018/tlnet-final is not signed`

Comment: Looks like url ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final require password now

Comment: If the ftp-link doesn't work (requires password), there are a couple of mirrors. See https://www.tug.org/historic/ for a full list.

Answer (score 17):

You don't *have* to upgrade at all, you can stop at tl2017 (*lots* of people installed tex  years ago and have never updated)

However if you want to update from one texlive to the next without doing a full install (which is the recommended route) then the texlive team have a page detailing what you need to do

https://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html

Note that this URL is exactly the address given in the error message that you quoted in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I see that `texlive` has an update mechanism, but it seems that it involves more effort than doing a fresh install altogether. On the other hand, I was looking for a quick fix like the answer below. Sorry If the question wasn't clear though.

Comment: @nikhilweee it is commands to type to do an in -place update but the usual reasons for doing it are to save download time by not doewnloading unchanged files and to save disk space by not having both versions installed.  If you do not have those requirements then simply installing the new version is of course easier.

Comment: This won't work: the user's TL is Debian's packaging. An in-place update would require an upstream installation. (At least, it certainly *should*.) I doubt such an update mechanism is designed to operate in user mode in such cases.

Comment: @cfr I did wonder (although most of the question applies to any TL) I thought the debian TL was always updated by the system apt-get, tlmgr also works does it? (if this answer is wrong, the debian packaged tlmgr's error message which gives the same link probably should be changed)

Comment: The main tree is updated with `apt`. But there's a kind of watered-down version of `tlmgr` which users can use to install particular packages themselves. `... switching to user mode!` is the give away. If this were upstream, it would not say that - either it would go ahead in sys mode or it would complain about permissions. I think the error message is supplied by the repository and not by `tlmgr`, but I'm not certain. I agree it is messed up, though.

Comment: The easiest/safest fix is probably the one I suggested: install the Debian package which provides `listings` using `apt`. This would avoid (at least in theory) any potential for version conflicts etc.

Comment: Note that the question is NOT about updating, but installing a package. A normal vanilla TL 2017 wouldn't lack `listings`. Of course, a system might not have scheme `full` installed, but a standard installation certainly would.

Comment: @cfr if you post an answer I'll add a note at the top of mine saying to see yours for debian packaged installs (or if you cover both I'll delete this, whichever you think best:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You said :
"You don't have to upgrade at all, you can stop at tl2017 (lots of people installed tex years ago and have never updated)"
What command should I type to stop at tl2017 ?

Comment: @SebMa I just meant don't upgrade. The tex upgrade from 2017 to 2018 is not automatic, it only happens if you actively install  the newer version.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't want to upgrade tex.But by your sentence, did you mean that when I see the error `tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)`, I don't have to type any command to prevent this error from showing up ?

Comment: @SebMa the site really does not work to ask multiple questions in comments on old answers. If you do not want to upgrade tex, do not use `tlmgr` and then you will not get warnings that it has failed.

Comment: the link states "By default, please get the new TL by doing a new installation instead of proceeding here. You don't need to remove an existing installation."

Comment: I need to clarify my comment: While they do state that doing a new install does not require removing the old one, they mean that doing so will lead to having multiple versions in parallel. Which is actually not what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

## TL; DR;

Get a fresh install of [TeX Live](https://tug.org/texlive/), though you said you don't want to. The installation is easy and the newer one would be distinguishable from the older ones.

## Story

I've been having `texlive-latex-base` by using `apt-get` on Ubuntu 18.04.
`sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base`

When I was trying converting a Markdown file to a pdf file using pandoc I originally ran into a problem [Error in TeX Live – Font … not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75166/error-in-tex-live-font-not-loadable-metric-tfm-file-not-found), then here.

But, immediately, I had a feeling that if I take one of these prescriptions I would be going through more uncertain problems in the later steps by intuition.

So, I decided to install an up-to-date version of [TeX Live](https://tug.org/texlive/).
Starting from there, please follow the directions on the web page and it will take some time, maybe hours depending on your network condition.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because although I installed the latest version of TexLive 
I didn't setup the PATH right. I would recommend if anyone has this issue to inspect
the PATH variable and run

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

to make sure that the `tlmgr` of new installation is discovered before any other already in the system.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, install 'MiKTeX' and typeset your document.

If 'listings' isn't installed when you start to typeset, it will install 'on the fly' ( if connected to the internet at the time ).

Comment: This appears to be a Microsoft-only solution.