# Revisited: tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, update

I have the same problem as [this guy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429714/44984), but the answers there do not help me.

```
» tlmgr install scrartcl
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

I have:

- installed and removed `texlive-latex-base`
- installed `texlive-base`
- tried to do a texlive upgrade, as described [here](https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html), but I gave up since that's insane.
- performed a full texlive install, as described [here](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html), which took over an hour

I still can not install the `scrartcl` package.

I am running on:

```
» lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 19 Tara
Release:        19
Codename:       tara
```

And this is my `tlmgr`:

```
» tlmgr version
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr revision 46207 (2018-01-04 19:34:36 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2017
```

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Please remove all those distribution packages, because they might prevent your newly installed TeX Live from being seen. And then you should follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge texlive-.*`