# Just installed texlive-full and it is outdated

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

I just did

```
sudo apt install texlive-full
```

Now I am running into some trouble getting packages to work.

I encountered this error:

```
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)
```

see als [tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429714/tlmgr-remote-repository-is-newer-than-local-2017-2018).

So it seems I have an outdated version and need to update it. But I have just installed what I thought was the most recent version. What did I do wrong? How do I install the most up to date version? (And how do uninstall the old on?)

---

On Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: You installed a Debian (Ubuntu?) repository version which is something bundled by your distro's maintainers. For an up to date TeX Live install the vanilla version from tug.org/texlive.

Comment: This is very well known. Most Linux dists offers out of date LaTeX installations and does not expect users to ever use `tlmgr`.

Comment: @daleif, Ok thanks. It is kind of impossible to expect this though before you actually encounter such a thing. Note that this method of installation is the answer for how to install texlive right here on stackexchange (https://askubuntu.com/questions/848949/how-to-install-texstudio-on-ubuntu-16-04). A comment that this installs an outdated version might be good to add there.

Comment: @Kvothe well all the Linuxes behave differently, some even take one years TeXLive before it is even released to the public, including all the unfixed bugs. So one would have to list all flavors of Linux... I do think there is an op to date 3rd party repository for Ubuntu that provides a more up to date TeXLive. Though, I tend to just use the upstream version.  (Note: if you are on a single user system, I'd recommend installing as yourself instead of installing as root)

Comment: Your related post (for which you indicate that it is "the answer for how to install texlive right here on stackexchange") is basically about installing an editor and someone just threw in that you also need the TeX distribution. Here on TeX.SX the usual recommendation (for Linux) is to use vanilla TeX Live (from TUG) unless you know that you will not rely on updated packages.