# tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018), No it is not

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, update

Ok, one more regarding this apparently [pervasive issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429714/tlmgr-remote-repository-is-newer-than-local-2017-2018) with `tlmgr` and Texlive and Linux and .... *sigh*.

1. So, I installed `texlive` on Ubuntu 18.04. So far so good.
2. Attempted to compile an article, I get: `LaTeX Error: File 'cuted.sty' not found. [\RequirePackage]`
3. Attempted `tlmgr install cuted`, get: `tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)`
4. Ok, so I install `texlive` 2018 following the instructions [here](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).
5. One hour downloading packages, good.
6. Added the paths to my `.profile` as instructed.
7. Test `tex --version`, I get `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2018)`. Looking good
8. Test `tlmgr version`, I get

   `tlmgr revision 49885 (2019-01-31 20:27:00 +0100)
    tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2018
    TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2018`. Even better.
9. Attempt `tlmgr install cuted`, I get `You don't have permission to change the installation in any way`. Ok.
10. Try `sudo tlmgr install cuted`, I get: `tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)`. *SIGH*.

So what now? What can I do? *I just need to compile this article please good god.*

Comment: don't know how helpful this may be but worth checking [export](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463216/170109) then restart as with all deep environmental settings a system memory refresh usually helps

Comment: My guess is that you now have two TeX systems installed. A (presumably) TeX live 2017 from the Ubuntu package sources and one vanilla TeX live 2018 from TUG. *Your* paths are set up in a way to give preference to the 2018 TeX live, but `sudo`'s paths are set up in a way to see the 2017 TeX live. I'm no Linux expert by in my limited experience it has not been enough to set the PATH as normally instructed to have `sudo` pick it up as well, that usually required additional work (I can't remember what exactly, though, sorry).

Comment: Maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83191 or https://askubuntu.com/q/128413/57634 can help if my guess was right.