# texlive 2018 install without update

Tags: paths, texlive-2018, update

I wonder if there is some workaround for the Texlive 2018 to be able to install any package, as right now everything is returning the error related to the new 2019 version.

There was [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429714/tlmgr-remote-repository-is-newer-than-local-2017-2018) answer, for the same problem in the version upgrade 2017 - 2018, and I tried the same reply (as admin):

```
tlmgr.bat info koma-script repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2018/tlnet-final
```

Perhaps the path is not the same anymore, or what can one do to if I cannot install the new version? My connection has problems and the download would take a really long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already have koma-script so have had to use koma-script-examples for illustration
You should **not attempt to run this type of install command through tlmgr.bat** since it has a different specific updater role.

It is better to run `tlmgr-gui` when you can. In that way I was able to quickly check if koma-script was already installed, this would be equivalent to the first part of your command.

```
tlmgr info koma-script
```

That command should confirm if koma-script is already installed (which in my case was confirmed by the feedback line `installed Yes`)

so in my case I switched to target the example files

```
\texlive\2018\bin\win32>tlmgr install koma-script-examples
```

> TeX Live 2018 is frozen forever and will no longer be updated.  This
>   happens in preparation for a new release.
>
> If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
>   pretests are available), please read
>   https://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html. Otherwise, just wait, and the
>   new release will be ready in due time.
>
> ```
> tlmgr.pl: package repository  
> ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2018/tlnet-final (not verified:  
> gpg unavailable) [1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: koma-script-examples  
> [551k] running mktexlsr ... done running mktexlsr. tlmgr.pl: package  
> log updated: /texlive/2018/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
> ```

```
\texlive\2018\bin\win32>tlmgr info koma-script-examples
```

> TeX Live 2018 is frozen forever and will no longer be updated.  This
>   happens in preparation for a new release.
>
> If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
>   pretests are available), please read
>   https://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html. Otherwise, just wait, and the
>   new release will be ready in due time.
>
> ```
> package:     koma-script-examples
> category:    Package
> shortdesc:   Examples from the KOMA-Script book
> longdesc:    This package contains some examples from the 6th edition of the book >>KOMA-Script<<, >>Eine Sammlung von Klassen und >> Paketen fur LaTeX2e<< by Markus Kohm, published by Lehmanns Media.
> There are no further descriptions of these examples.
> ```
>
> **installed:   Yes**
>
> ```
> revision:    47523
> sizes:       doc: 1665k
> relocatable: No
> cat-date:    2018-04-23 05:04:11 +0200
> cat-license: lppl1.3c
> cat-topics:  book-ex
> collection:  collection-langgerman
> ```

As you can see my 2018 installation is now defaulting to the historic repository

There are several ways that can be done and the easiest way which I have already told you is to use tlmgr-gui the other way is to use tlmgr direct and either set the default via the option command or change your command line slightly

```
tlmgr install koma-script --repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2018/tlnet-final
```