# Upgrade to 2019 gone wrong on a Debian System

Tags: updating, unix

I followed the advice at
[tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429714/tlmgr-remote-repository-is-newer-than-local-2017-2018) and upgraded my TeX installation following the tutorial at https://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html.

When I ran the `update-tlmgr-latest.sh` script, using

```
sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh
```

I obtained:

```
sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater  100%  
./runme.sh: updating in /usr/local/texlive/2019...
./runme.sh: tlmgr version says this is TeX Live 2018,
./runme.sh: and this updater script created: Thu Feb  7 02:56:31 CET 2019.
./runme.sh: proceeding with tlmgr update.
./runme.sh: updating /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux ...
./runme.sh: /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr including objects: master/tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.tlpobj master/tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.x86_64-linux.tlpobj
D:tlmgr:main: ::tldownload_server defined: TeXLive::TLDownload=HASH(0x5631e5578850)
D:setup_programs: preferring system versions
D:trying to set up system curl, arg --version
D:program curl found in the path
D:trying to set up system wget, arg --version
D:program wget found in the path
D:trying to set up system lz4, arg --version
D:program lz4 not usable from path
D:(unix) trying to set up lz4, default /usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/installer/lz4/lz4.x86_64-linux, arg --version
D:Using shipped /usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/installer/lz4/lz4.x86_64-linux for lz4 (tested).
D:trying to set up system gzip, arg --version
D:program gzip found in the path
D:trying to set up system xz, arg --version
D:program xz found in the path
DD:dumping $::progs = {
  'compressor' => 'lz4',
  'curl' => 'curl',
  'gzip' => 'gzip',
  'lz4' => '/usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/installer/lz4/lz4.x86_64-linux',
  'tar' => 'tar',
  'wget' => 'wget',
  'working_compressors' => [
    'lz4',
    'gzip',
    'xz'
  ],
  'working_downloaders' => [
    'curl',
    'wget'
  ],
  'xz' => 'xz'
};
./runme.sh: done.
```

The "done" lead me to think that the upgrade went smoothly, but I'm afraid it did not.

`tlmgr update --self --all`
returns

```
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2018 < 2019)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

and `tex -v` starts by `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2018)`.

What's wrong?

Comment: And, BTW, isn't the message returned by `tlmgr update --self --all` wrong? If I try `sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh --update`,  I get `Unrecognized flag : --update`.

Comment: you need to change your PATH you have 2018 and 2019 installed and your PATH is still pointing at 2018

Comment: that is what do `which tex` and `which tlmgr` report?

Comment: They both point to the correct location (i.e., `/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/`), both as root and as normal user.

Comment: well that's weird... sorry no other ideas. where did you change the path though, the default install does not do that

Comment: It is weird, but somehow I tried one more time … and it worked. It's getting weirder (I was in the same terminal, did not changed anything, did not re-load any configuration file). I'm still posting an answer instead of deleting my question, in case someone faces the same strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how I solved my issue, but I did:

1. Delete `update-tlmgr-latest.sh`
2. Re-download `update-tlmgr-latest.sh` from http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
3. Run the script again, from the `/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/` folder, using (as root) `sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh`.
4. Had the same output as the one posted in the question.
5. Ran (still as root, still in the same folder) `tlmgr update --self --all`.

And this time it worked:

```
> tlmgr update --self --all 
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/backups
[  1/489] auto-remove: psu-thesis ... done
[  2/489] auto-remove: mbenotes ... done
```

etc.

I have no idea why it worked this time, my `PATH` variables were correctly set in

- `/etc/login.defs`
- `/ etc/environment`
- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.bashrc`