# Undefined subroutine error when running biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I am trying to compile tex document using biblatex to handle references with no success. I am aware of the cycle Latex > Biber > Latex. I always use pdflatex, therefore it should be

```
pdflatex main.tex
biber main[.bcf]
pdflatex main.tex
```

In the first step, I get e.g. `Citation 'citekey' on page 53 undefined` which is normal as I have not generated the proper reference text. But upon running `biber main` I get error

`Undefined subroutine &Biber::Config::biber_error called at /var/folders/zv/ds3zw_xs2dv4c1jp7m1t44f80000gt/T/par-6973776168797574616d61/cache-ec7adafccc6b3891989ad6eb09778d44c1fecb97/inc/lib/Biber/Config.pm line 640.`
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is your tex system and what does biber --version says?

Comment: What do you mean by tex system? `biber -v` returns `biber version: 2.11`.

Comment: miktex or texlive?

Comment: Running `pdflatex -v` gives in the first line `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)`. So, I think its texlive.

Comment: You can try to delete the cache (the folder starting with `par-69737761687...` (at the next run biber will need some time to unpack itself, so be patient). The last biber version in tl2018 was 2.12 so you could also try to update. You probably need a historic repository for this. Adapt e.g. this answer  to 2018: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429718/2388.

Comment: where do I find `par-69737761687...` folder?

Comment: Your error message above shows the complete path (starting with /var/)

Comment: Run `biber --cache` and you'll see the location.

Comment: There used to be an infamous Biber/`PAR::Packer` bug with similar symptoms: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864. Since the issue was fixed in PAR::Packer a while ago I haven't seen many people complaining about this. But maybe there are still edge cases that aren't fixed. Follow the steps in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864 to delete your Biber cache. Then run Biber again, but make sure not to abort the Biber run. Since Biber has to unpack a few things, the first run may take a while - do not stop it.

Comment: Any news here? Errors like this are a bit tricky and so any feedback or hints you could provide for people with the same problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate of the infamous cache bug. But in case it turns out that this did not help or your can provide more info on the issue, feel free to ping me and we can reopen the question with more details.