# Issue with TeX Live Shell

Tags: texlive, windows, tlmgr, texlive-2019

I have an issue with tlmgr GUI. Whenever I start TeX Live Manager on my Windows 10 machine, the GUI is 2x the normal size and the list of packages is blank. Please see the picture.

[image]

To get TeX Live Manager to show the list of packages, I would need to choose "Load repository" under File menu. Does anyone have the same issue?

Thanaset

Comment: Ye, I have the same kinda, for me the GUI is normal size, but the list of packages is empty too, When I switch from "all" to "collections and schemes" and then back to "all", then it shows the packages (dont need to load repo).
In addition I can't load most of the repos, it shows a message box with "back end gone. ..." It started with TL 2020, so maybe its broken somehow.

Comment: @A.Ston Thanks for responding. It's relief to learn that I'm not the only one with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As to not showing packages at startup: this should be fixed at the next update of tlshell.
As to display size: tlshell now tries to guess whether the display is HiDPI. If so, it displays everything at double size. Anyhow, you can now change font size via the options menu and via Ctrl- and Ctrl= key combinations.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots showing how to solve the given issue?

Answer (score 0):

[tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429714/tlmgr-remote-repository-is-newer-than-local-2017-2018)

The solution here (Run tlmgr option repository.... and change the year to 2019) fixes this error for me. It appears that Tex Live is updating to a 2020 version and the manager expects you to have a 2020 version of Tex Live (Which you don't have, I assume), and so it crashes.

Comment: @A Person: Hmmm .. I'm not sure if that would help as I have got TeX Live 2020 installed. But thanks for the responding anyway. Cheers.