# Fedora with Concrete Math: Font … not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, errors, math-fonts, linuxfedora

This question is similar to this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75166/error-in-tex-live-font-not-loadable-metric-tfm-file-not-found), but related to Fedora30 and the Concrete Math package.

My error are:

```
Reports/test_font/main.tex:25: Font OML/ccm/m/it/10=xccmi10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

Reports/test_font/main.tex:25: Font OML/ccm/m/it/7=xccmi7 at 7.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

/Reports/test_font/main.tex:25: Font OML/ccm/m/it/5=xccmi5 at 5.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

with the following minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
    % General document formatting
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    % Related to math
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{concmath}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % mathematical fonts
    \usepackage{ccfonts}  % mathematical fonts
    \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ccr}% cmr = Computer Modern Roman

    \usepackage{libertine}


\begin{document}

Name, date, Exercise X

Math in line $ y(t) = (h \ast x)(t)$
Math equation
\begin{equation}
    y(t) = \sum_{k=0}^K \alpha_k \delta(t - \tau_k)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\gamma f=\sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k)\mathrm{Res}(f;a_k)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I am using Fedora 30 with a fresh minimal installation of texlive via `dnf` which does not ship `tlmgr`.
As explained in the answers of the above-linked question, I installed `texlive-collection-fontsrecommended` as well as `texlive-concrete` for Concrete Math Fonts and the .fm and .tfm are in the texmf's font folder.

I am compiling latex through VSCode and I also have the same error using `pdflatex main.tex` comman in the shell. Is there a way to force latex to check a target folder? I also tried on overleaf and the compilation works fine.

Is the a way to

Any help? Thank you

Comment: Welcome! Misspelling [Cthulhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cthulhu) can have severe consequences. (Just kidding ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora ships the missing font metric files (e.g. `xccmi10.tfm`) in the [`texlive-concmath-fonts`](https://fedora.pkgs.org/31/fedora-x86_64/texlive-concmath-fonts-svn17218.0-27.fc31.noarch.rpm.html) package. Installing that should solve the issue:

```
dnf install texlive-concmath-fonts
```

Comment: It works!  I tried `dnf install texlive-concmath` but it was not solving the issue. Adding `-fonts` was the keys. Thank you very much

Comment: Running this with Fedora 31, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Arsak Which error message do you get? Which `texlive-concmath*` packages are installed?