# Font T2A/cmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts

This is my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
Hello, \foreignlanguage{russian}{друг}!
\end{document}
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm larm1000
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for larm1000.
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input larm1000
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf larm1000
! I can't find file `larm1000'.
<*> ...four; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input larm1000

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...four; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input larm1000

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: larm1000.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input larm1000' failed to make larm1000.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T2A/cmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fo
und.
<to be read again>
                   relax
l.6 Hello, \foreignlanguage{russian}{друг}
                                              !
?
```

What could be wrong? I'm at Ubuntu 20.04 with TeX Live 2021:

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021)
kpathsea version 6.3.3
Copyright 2021 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

BTW, I tried to find this file, but it's not there: `tlmgr search --file larm1000.tfm --global`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75166/error-in-tex-live-font-not-loadable-metric-tfm-file-not-found

Comment: @Saravanan I've seen that, but still no luck, the file `larm1000.tfm` is not visible in the tlnet

Comment: `tlmgr install lh` might do, but it's better to install the whole `collection-langcyrillic`

Comment: @egreg this was the solution, thanks! Please, make it an answer and we close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tfm` files of the `lh` family are generated on demand. This is why you see

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm larm1000
```

How do I know the name of the font family? Common knowledge, I'm afraid.

You might do `tlmgr install lh`, but you also need the `cm-super` TeX Live package for Type1 fonts.

From your name I guess you'll be using Cyrillic a lot, so it's best to install the whole `langcyrillic` collection. If I do

```
tlmgr info collection-langcyrillic --list
```

I get

```
package:     collection-langcyrillic
category:    Collection
shortdesc:   Cyrillic
longdesc:    Support for Cyrillic scripts (Bulgarian, Russian, Serbian, Ukrainian), even if Latin alphabets may also be used.
installed:   Yes
revision:    54074
sizes:       50553k
relocatable: No
depends:
    babel-belarusian
    babel-bulgarian
    babel-russian
    babel-serbian
    babel-serbianc
    babel-ukrainian
    churchslavonic
    cmcyr
    collection-basic
    collection-latex
    cyrillic
    cyrillic-bin
    cyrplain
    disser
    eskd
    eskdx
    gost
    hyphen-belarusian
    hyphen-bulgarian
    hyphen-churchslavonic
    hyphen-mongolian
    hyphen-russian
    hyphen-serbian
    hyphen-ukrainian
    lcyw
    lh
    lhcyr
    lshort-bulgarian
    lshort-mongol
    lshort-russian
    lshort-ukr
    mongolian-babel
    montex
    mpman-ru
    numnameru
    pst-eucl-translation-bg
    ruhyphen
    russ
    serbian-apostrophe
    serbian-date-lat
    serbian-def-cyr
    serbian-lig
    t2
    texlive-ru
    texlive-sr
    ukrhyph
    xecyrmongolian
Included files, by type:
```

You might not need some of these TeX Live packages, but…