# How can I prevent LGR encoding from switching font size?

Tags: fontsize, package-writing, font-encodings, documentclass-writing

I am using 12pt fonts with what is essentially the `article` class. (That is, I'm using a custom class which is parasitic on `article.cls`.)

In order to set an appropriate `headheight` for `fancyhdr` using `\geometry{}`, I test the font size at the end of the preamble using `\AtEndPreamble{}` from `etoolbox`. The height is then adjusted according to whether 10pt, 11pt or 12pt is being used.

This all works fine with the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \PackageWarning{mine}{font size is \f@size}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

some text

\end{document}
```

The log contains:

```
Package mine Warning: font size is 12 on input line 13.
```

However, if I need to typeset Greek, I want to use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \PackageWarning{mine}{font size is \f@size}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

some text

\end{document}
```

Only now the log contains:

```
Package mine Warning: font size is 10 on input line 13.
```

Why does loading the LGR encoding change the font size at all? And why does it change it even when T1 is the default encoding?

How can I prevent or work around this problem?

Note that I am aware that I could use XeTeX or LuaTeX or ConTeXt to avoid this. However, for better or worse, this question is about a (pdf)TeX solution.

If there is an alternative way of typesetting small amounts of Greek text using (pdf)TeX, that would be perfectly satisfactory. I use the above with `utf8` and `inputenc` which allows me to input the odd Greek phrase in unicode characters and have everything typeset nicely. Anything which supports that would work fine.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18747/polutonikogreek-with-lmodern-12pt) seemed related but I am using TeX Live and already have the relevant type1 fonts installed (e.g. `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cbfonts/grmn1200.pfb`).

Comment: @jon Unfortunately, that won't work. `\AtEndPreamble` is a test in a class/package file which tests which font size has been selected in the document. It would defeat the purpose to hard code a value since in that case, I might as well just hard code the `headheight`.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pdftex] tag as this also applies to 'classical' TeX!

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks. I tried to find a suitable tag for (TeX + pdfTeX) but couldn't find one. I wanted one for that group as opposed to ConTeXt/LuaTeX/XeTeX. Is there a tag for that?

Comment: @cfr No. We had some discussion I think about input encodings on meta: as encodings are essentially TeX90/e-TeX/pdfTeX rather than XeTeX/LuaTeX issues it seemed natural for this to follow from an encoding tag.

Comment: My feeling is that you can rely on the font size only after `\normalsize` has been issued, which it is at `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rely on the font size only after `\normalsize` has been issued. This is part of `\begin{document}`.

I see no problem in setting `\headheight` as part of

```
\AtBeginDocument{...}
```

rather than `\AtEndPreamble`. However, doing

```
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \normalsize
  \PackageWarning{mine}{font size is \f@size}
}
```

prints

```
Package mine Warning: font size is 12 on input line 11.
```

in the `.log` file.

Comment: Thanks. I was using `\AtBeginDocument{}` but I switched to `\AtEndPreamble{}` as it was not effective. I'm using `\geometry{}` to set headheight. As I understand it, I need to do this in the preamble. If I do it in the document, I can use `\newgeometry{}` but I don't want to wipe everything else. I only want to change headheight at this point. Using `\AtEndPreamble` seemed to solve that issue until I tried using `LGR` encoding. However, if I can use `\normalsize` in `\AtEndPreamble`, that would indeed solve the issue.

Comment: `\normalsize` in `\AtEndPreamble` seems to work well with using `\geometry{headheight= }`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The file `lgrenc.def` includes the line

```
\DeclareErrorFont{LGR}{cmr}{m}{n}{10}
```

and it's this that causes the change of font size. This command resets `\f@size` amongst other things (taken from `ltfssbas.dtx`):

```
%  \begin{macro}{\DeclareErrorFont}
%    Declare the last resort shape! We assume that in this fontshape
%    there is a 10pt font but it doesn't really matter. We only loose
%    one macro name if the assumption is false. But at least the font
%    should be there!
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\DeclareErrorFont#1#2#3#4#5{%
      \xdef\error@fontshape{%
          \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\split@name\noexpand\string
          \expandafter\noexpand\csname#1/#2/#3/#4/#5\endcsname
          \noexpand\@nil}%
%    \end{macrocode}
%    Initialize all those internal variables which may or may not have
%    values in the first seconds of NFSS' bootstraping process. Later
%    on such values will be updated when an encoding is selected, etc.
%
%    We definitely don't want to set |\f@encoding|; we can set all the
%    others since if they are left ``blank'' any selection would grap
%    ``error default values'' as well. However, this probably should
%    go also.
% \changes{v2.1n}{1994/05/14}{Don't set \cs{f@encoding}}
%    \begin{macrocode}
%      \gdef\f@encoding{#1}%
      \gdef\default@family{#2}%
      \gdef\default@series{#3}%
      \gdef\default@shape{#4}%
      \global\let\f@family\default@family
      \global\let\f@series\default@series
      \global\let\f@shape\default@shape
      \gdef\f@size{#5}%
      \gdef\f@baselineskip{#5pt}%
}
\@onlypreamble\DeclareErrorFont
%    \end{macrocode}
%  \end{macro}
```

As you can see, this is based on the idea some other reset will take place later.

Other encodings don't alter the fall-back, so you never see the fact that this also resets the size.

I guess in terms of 'how do I prevent this', you would have to locally disable `\DeclareErrorFont` (not ideal!).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\savedDeclareErrorFont\DeclareErrorFont
\def\DeclareErrorFont#1#2#3#4#5{}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\let\DeclareErrorFont\savedDeclareErrorFont
\makeatletter
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \PackageWarning{mine}{font size is \f@size}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. Is there a good way to avoid the issues this raises?

Comment: @cfr Report it as a LaTeX bug, perhaps?

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks. Would it be possible to save the font size early in the class/package and then restore it at the end of the preamble? I tried `\global\let\save@fontsize\f@size` to save it and `\global\let\f@size\save@fontsize` to restore it - which seemed to work but I'm not sure whether it is at all safe. [Actually, this isn't what I tried first but this is the first thing which did not send pdfTeX into an infinite hang.] I see that `\DeclareErrorFont` also sets `baselineskip` to the same value. That seems odd?

Comment: *Where* do LaTeX bugs get reported?

Comment: @cfr http://latex-project.org/bugs.html

Comment: http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/4399