# Converting preamble into a new class changes margins

Tags: margins, documentclass-writing

I'm trying to convert a preamble into a new class file.

This is a simplfied version of the original file: `testdoc.tex`

```
\documentclass[%
   11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright, titlepage, fleqn,%
   headinclude, footinclude, BCOR5mm,%
   numbers=noenddot, cleardoublepage=empty,%
   ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,beramono,listings,%
                eulermath,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{arsclassica}

\title{Pràctiques de laboratori\\ Wireshark}
\author{Fonaments de xarxes de telecomunicació}
\date{Curs 15/16}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle
%\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Then the whole preamble is converted into `testclass.cls` file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]%
\ProvidesClass{FXTWShark}[2015/07/30 Format Enunciat Pràctiques FXT]

\LoadClass[%
   11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright, titlepage, fleqn,%
   headinclude, footinclude, BCOR5mm,%
   numbers=noenddot, cleardoublepage=empty,%
   ]{scrreprt}

\RequirePackage[english,spanish,catalan]{babel}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[export]{adjustbox}
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\RequirePackage[eulerchapternumbers,beramono,listings,%
                eulermath,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\RequirePackage{arsclassica}
```

which is used as document class in `testclass.tex`

```
\documentclass{testclass}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Once compiled the result is a layout with different header and footer margins

[image]

Do you know why?

May be the problem is related with [Defined a new class verbatim from my preamble, but resulting document does not have identical layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222077/defined-a-new-class-verbatim-from-my-preamble-but-resulting-document-does-not-h) but the answer there or [egreg's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203505/1952) cited answer to  [How can I prevent LGR encoding from switching font size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203493/how-can-i-prevent-lgr-encoding-from-switching-font-size) doesn't help me. I'm not sure about the relation and I if they are, I don't know how to apply it to my problem.

Comment: don't forgget `\ProvidesClass{testclass}` and `\endinput` see egreg answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is looking in the log file where

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [headinclude,footinclude].
```

is found. The two options pertain to `typearea` and not to `scrreprt`. With the first example code, they are global options, because they are passed to `\documentclass`, in the second case they aren't and so `typearea` doesn't see them.

Solution: use `\PassOptionsToPackage`.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2015/07/30 Format Enunciat Pràctiques FXT]

\PassOptionsToPackage{headinclude,footinclude,BCOR=5mm}{typearea}

\LoadClass[
   11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright, titlepage, fleqn,
   numbers=noenddot, cleardoublepage=empty,
   ]{scrreprt}

\RequirePackage[english,spanish,catalan]{babel}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[export]{adjustbox}
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\RequirePackage[eulerchapternumbers,beramono,listings,
                eulermath,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\RequirePackage{arsclassica}

\endinput
```

[image]

Comment: I think the BCOR option needs an equal sign by now, the syntax above is obsolete. Also possible and more intuitive: Give the options using `KOMAoptions`, maybe followed by `recalctypearea`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, I'm no expert in KOMA classes.